# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `Editor`, expected `string`

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, antd

```js
<Form
  form={form}
  initialValues={{
  content: postDetail.content,
  }}
  onFinish={onFinish}
>
   <Form.Item name="content">
     <Editor onEditorChange={handleEditorChange} init={INIT} />
   </Form.Item>
        
   <Form.Item>
     <StyledButton htmlType="submit" type="primary" height={45} width={240}>
         Submit
     </StyledButton>
   </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

I using `tinymce` editor combined with form of antd design to create a create post page.
When I load the page and change some text in the editor the debugger shows the warning like the code bellow. How I fix it:

```
 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `Editor`, expected `string`.
    in Editor (at CreateForm/index.jsx:151)
    in Field (created by WrapperField)
    in WrapperField (created by FormItem)
    in FormItem (at CreateForm/index.jsx:150)
    in div (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div (at CreateForm/index.jsx:138)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Col (at CreateForm/index.jsx:137)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
```

Comment: what is the value of INIT? and can you show us handleEditorChange?

Comment: Did you get this one figured out? I have the same issue and I'm researching it now.

Comment: Do you have a solution for it now? I get the same error but only happens the first time on edit.